# Who is the actor that played Drift in the Fortnite Season 5 trailer?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

In the [Fortnite Chapter 1 Season 5 Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3UNnrr1pg4&ab_channel=Fortnite) there's a small section of the video that's live action where we see Drift in the real world before he's brought into game world by a Rift. Since it's live action they obviously had to have somebody play the part of Drift, but who? Who is the actor that appears as Drift in the trailer?

Answer (score 1):

The actor who played drift in the fortnite season 5 trailer is Tyler Osterkamp.

Comment: downvoter, could you explain where im wrong? maybe i read a source wrong but im pretty sure that the guy.

Comment: Wait is this wrong? I'm honestly confused why this was flagged? Anyway I upvoted :), you're at least at 0 now. As a note to whoever flagged: don't flag just because you think an answer is wrong (if that's why you did it)

Comment: @Penguin no im pretty sure its right, which is why im confused as to why its downvoted, maybe they think its too short or something?

Comment: yep, I'm even more confused bc whoever did flagged it for its content